# Firestore - How to do a .set() on multi-level document

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I can't seem to find the answer to this in the Firestore documentation, but if I wanted to do something as simple as this, in my Angular 6 application:

```
firebase.firestore().collection(`fb_ad_accounts`).doc(`${adAccountId}/${id}`).set({
  name: name,
  id: id,
  date_created: new Date().getTime()
})
```

I get an error that says

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but fb_ad_accounts/779737999495825/249155905774166 has 3
```

I'd like to build my data like this, but I can't figure out how to do a simple `add()` to a tree that looks like `fb_ad_accounts/<account_id>/<ad_account_id>`

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firestore, a document may contain only fields with values.  A document cannot contain another documents.

Documents may have subcollections organized underneath them (that each may have their own documents), but these subcollections are not technically contained in the document itself.

The error message essentially is reminding you of these facts, but in a somewhat mathematical way.

If you want a document to appear "nested" within another document, you'll have to choose the name of a subcollection where it will appear.  For example:

```
fb_ad_accounts/<account_id>/ads/<ad_account_id>
```

Note the "ads" subcollection appears underneath the  document.  Mathematically speaking, it's a valid path for a document because it has an even number of path components (4).

Comment: hmm interesting, so is this a bit of a work around? With realtime database, I know you could structure databases like this so that you could query just `fb_ad_accounts/<account_id>` and get all of the ad accounts in that tree. That's basically what I'm trying to do here. By adding that `ads`, it's introducing another layer that I have to account for on my client. Is this the only way?

Comment: Queries in Firestore are shallow - they don't look inside subcollections of matched documents.  Queries in Realtime Database are deep - everything under a node is retrieved.  This leads to different modeling and querying, and there is not really a "workaround".  They are just different.  You'll have to do one query/get to fetch the document of interest, then another query for each subcollection that you also need.

Comment: that makes sense. So then I'm a little confused on how I would need to structure a query to grab the data from (in our example) `fb_ad_accounts/<account_id>/ads`. Doing a `firebase.firestore().doc(`fb_ad_accounts/${adAccountId}/ads`).get().then()` results in another error about an `even number of segments` issue and I can't find the documentation that outlines what to do in an example like this :/

Comment: Use collection() instead of doc() to build a collection reference.

Comment: BTW if you have more questions, it's conventional to start another question on SO rather than extending the comments section like this.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's true. I'll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks for the help on this one, I did end up figuring it out!